# Adding Django Groups Programatically

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have set up a very basic Django website and I am looking to create a moderator group. I am unsure how to go about creating this programatically. Mainly, I am worried about which file I would need to put it in, and whether or not when I create it, will it show up on my admin site as a group. Otherwise, how else can I confirm it is made? Can I create groups from any app? For example, I have an app called 'users' which doesn't contain any models. Can I simply create my moderator group with example code for a generic group below in views.py or will that not work?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from api.models import Project
new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='new_group')

ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Project)

permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_add_project',
                               name='Can add project',
                               content_type=ct)
 new_group.permissions.add(permission)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.6 on 2021-09-15 10:13

from django.db import  models, migrations

def apply_migration(apps, schema_editor):
Group = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')
Group.objects.bulk_create([
    Group(name=u'group1'),
    Group(name=u'group2'),
    Group(name=u'group3'),
])


def revert_migration(apps, schema_editor):
Group = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')
Group.objects.filter(
    name__in=[
        u'group1',
        u'group2',
        u'group3',
    ]
).delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('users', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(apply_migration, revert_migration)
]
```

Comment: Django already has something as a moderator group: you can set `is_superuser` to `True`, such users then have *all* the permissions in the sense that `has_perm` will always return `True`.

Comment: If you want to make an extra `Group`, then you can work with a data migration.

Comment: I was looking to make a custom group, how could I go about using migrations? I tried to create a new migration file through the command line and add code but I only got 'circularError', so I'm trying to see if there was another way.

Comment: can you share your migration file.

Comment: Added to the post.

Comment: what if you remove the `models` from the `
from django.db import  models, migrations` such that you only import `migrations`?

Comment: still a circulardependencyerror